# Counting the number of specified words

Tags: python, count, nltk

I want to count the number of *'america'* and *'citizen'* in the *'inaugural'* files on the files that start with *1789* and *1793* .

```
cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
           (target, file[:4])
               for fileid in inaugural.fileids()
               for w in inaugural.words(fileid)
               for target in ['america', 'citizen']
               if w.lower().startswith(target))

year = ['1789', '1793']
word = ['america', 'citizen']
cfd.tabulate(conditions=year, samples=word)
```

It didn't count the word correctly. what's the problem?
note: I want to show the 'america' and 'citizen' as column and the years as row. 
my out put:

```
    america citizen 
1789    0    0 
1793    0    0
```

Comment: use `count()` function. Google -> Python count function --> Result.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions and samples are the opposite order, `ConditionalFreqDist` constructor takes `condition, sample`, yet you give it `sample, condition`. Try:

```
cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
           (fileid[:4], target)
               for fileid in inaugural.fileids()
               for w in inaugural.words(fileid)
               for target in ['america', 'citizen']
               if w.lower().startswith(target))

A = ['1789', '1793']
B = ['america', 'citizen']
cfd.tabulate(conditions=A, samples=B)
```

outputs

```
     america citizen 
1789    2    5 
1793    1    1
```

---

In general case you'd want to use a stemmer, thus getting something like:

```
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer

stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')
cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
       (fileid[:4], stemmer.stem(word))
           for fileid in inaugural.fileids()
           for word in inaugural.words(fileid))

A = ['2009', '2005']
B = [stemmer.stem(i) for i in ['freedom', 'war']]
cfd.tabulate(conditions=A, samples=B)
```

resulting in output

```
     freedom  war 
2009    3    2
2005   27    0
```

Comment: Interesting, OP's post matches the [example in the docs](http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/kit/2009s/clt231/NLTK/book/ch02-AccessingTextCorporaAndLexicalResources.html#ref-first-four-chars) which uses ```(target, fileid[:4])```

Comment: your code works better. but i don't  know why it doesn't  always give me correct result. I count a specific word by eyes. the program gives different result !! (i.e sometimes the program gives wrong result)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm, you can use [count](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_count.htm) function;

```
print (mystring.count("specificword"))
```

A demo;

```
mystring = "hey hey hi hello hey hello hi"
print (mystring.count("hey"))

>>> 
3
>>>
```

The rest, depends on you. Display them like a table is basically manipulate them with `print` function. Another demo;

```
mystring = "hey hey hi hello hey hello hi"

a = mystring.count("hey")
b = mystring.count("hi")
c = mystring.count("hello")

obj = """hey: {}
hi: {}
hello {}"""

print (obj.format(a,b,c))
```

output;

```
>>> 
hey: 3
hi: 2
hello 2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nltk.sent_tokenize` to create a list of word then use `collections.Counter` to grub a dictionary that the words are its key and frequency of words is the value :

from collections import Counter

```
with open(file) as f:
        C=Counter(nltk.sent_tokenize(f.lower()))
        B = ['america', 'citizen']
        for i in B:
            print C[i]
```